# Cannot make stash:get to show up inside exp:channel tag

Tags: stash, channel, parse-order, embeds

Problem:

A value set is not parsed inside a channel:entries tag.

The value is actually set (and parsed with the embed on the page).

Also, when I hard-code the value in te channel:entries tag the result appears, so there is nothing wrong with the channel code.

I want get this value:

```
{exp:stash:set
     name="MedlemLetterAuthor"
 }
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="member_profiles"
        dynamic_parameters="search:member_letter"
        orderby="title"
        sort="asc"
        dynamic="off"}
    {author_id}|
    {/exp:channel:entries}
 {/exp:stash:set}
```

### This is my embed:

```
begin test
    just for testing: {exp:stash:get
         name="MedlemLetterAuthor"
     }
end test

{exp:stash:parse
process="end"
trim="yes"}



        {exp:channel:entries
                            channel="kcvast_arbet|kcvast_offentlig"
                            disable="pagination|category-fields|member-data"
                            dynamic="no"
                            author_id="{stash:MedlemLetterAuthor}"
                            orderby="author_id"
                            parse="inward"
                            }
                            {off-gest-bilder
                            cover_only="yes"
                            }some channel code here
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

---

### This appears on my page

```
begin test
    just for testing: 

        8|

        46|


end test
```

---

Answer (score 1):

In your embed code you have pasted it looks like you have an extra pipe character in your author_id parameter

```
author_id="{stash:get name="MedlemLetterAuthor"}|"parse="inward"
```

makes it a little hard to understand what the code is supposed to be. Perhaps its just a typo. The other thing to try would be what is suggested in this thread.

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/stash/viewthread/7166

Sometimes I find using single quotes within double quotes of parameters helps as well for example

```
author_id="{stash:get name='MedlemLetterAuthor'}"
```

Comment: Thanks. The extra pipeline is there because the result can be more then one author_id and the tag accepts that (checked that by hardcoding it)

Comment: I have seen the methode used in the discussion you mention and checked that out, but, I will test that solution again.

Comment: Still confused on the pipe. Stash would output whatever is in it and then the pipe would be added after it. So if stash held multiple authors wouldn't it output author_id="author1author2author3|"

Comment: You are absolute right about the pipeline, it sould be inside what Stash picks up, not in output. (was typo from earlier version ;-)

Comment: But, unfortunately this example does noting for me, I edited the example with the code I use now.

Comment: Just checking because it is not in your code. Do you have a {/exp:stash:parse} tag at the end of that code?

Comment: Sorry to have letting this go unanswered. Your suggestion: -------Sometimes I find using single quotes within double quotes of parameters helps as well for example

author_id="{stash:get name='MedlemLetterAuthor'}" ----- did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the output the stash is capturing white space and EE doesn't like that for var values.

When setting your initial stash, add the param `trim="yes"` - this will remove any whitespace.

**Update**
Your stash var: MedlemLetterAuthor should output in 1 line: 1|38|9999 etc. As I wrote initially add the trim to THE FIRST SET STASH!!!!!!

Comment: I am sorry to report that did did not help.

Comment: Add the trim part to your first stash where you aet the var - not the parse stash.